# Is my code inefficient or is my task hard?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

hope someone can help here?

I've written some code to perform a look-up task, and it's taking a long time to do it––far longer than it seems it should. For confidentiality reasons, I can't describe the exact task, but I can give one that's directly analogous.

Let's say that I have a database containing a list of words and a set of values corresponding to these words. Say, colours and how much these colours are liked.

Now, I have a text, and I want to compare all the words in this text to my database of colours, and where a match exists, I extract the 'liking' rating from the database and record it. When all words in the text have been matched (or not) with the database, the sum of the 'liking' ratings is my output.

An equivalent to the code I've written is below, and it works fine for the toy example I've given. However, my actual problem contains a database of 40k entries, and the text typically has about 500 words; most of the words in the text will be in the database. And when I run it, it takes hours to execute. I understand that matching 500 words against a database of 40k entries means on the order of 20m comparisons. Still, *hours*?

Can anyone suggest whether I'm doing a computationally intensive problem with limited hardware, or of my code is just massively inefficient?

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk as nltk

####### Creates toy data to test code on ###

colour = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'colour': ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

dfs = [df1, df2]

###### Code proper begins below

data = pd.concat(dfs, axis = 1) ######## Dataframe


#### Sample words 
words = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'cyan', 'white', 'black', 'pink', 'grey', 'scarlet']


#### Lists into which words are put post-analysis
rating = 0
rated = []
unrated = []

####### Code

for i in words:
    for j in range(len(data['colour'])):
        if i == data['colour'][j]: 
            rating = rating + data['value'][j]
            rated.append(i)
            break
        elif i not in unrated and i not in data.values: ### Ensures each unrated word is entered only once.
            unrated.append(i)
```

Comment: An efficient solution won't be iterative. I'd suggest looking into hash trees or like structures. There's a reason a map lookup is near-constant-time regardless of size.

Comment: ...which is to say: It's the design inefficiencies rather than the implementation ones that jump out to me here. If you want to use a tool that's very, very good at this kind of thing, consider a SQL database with appropriate indexes created? Some databases support full-text indexing, which is particularly apropos.

Comment: Fair enough, though I'm stuck with Python for now, so and SQL solution won't work. I'll look into hash trees, though.

Comment: "Stuck with Python" doesn't necessarily imply "SQL won't work". Isn't the sqlite module built into python out-of-the-box these days? You don't even need an out-of-process daemon for that -- and while its query optimizer is underpowered compared to the big boys in the field, what you're doing here shouldn't need that.

Comment: ...and yes, SQLite does have full-text search support: https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: Very useful suggestion if SQLite is out-of-the box as you suggest. I'll look into this going forward.  Still interested from a purely academic perspective as to why the original code is so disastrously slow, so I'll keep the question going for that if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You need to index your keywords so that each word in your text can be looked up in O(1) time. If the dataset can fit in memory (and with 40k words it should be no problem), it can be as simple as this:

```
sentiment_index = dict(zip(colour, values))
rated = set()

for i in words:
    i = i.lower()
    rating += sentiment_index.get(i, 0)
    rated.add(i)
```

You could also write `rating += sentiment_index[i]`, which is equally fast. But then you'd need an existence check, which I avoid by using `get()` with a default. And of course I added a set for the rated words. If you really do need to delegate lookups to a database, add an index to your dataframe to speed up lookups.

Comment: This is really, really good; it cuts straight to the core of the problem. Thank you very much! I'll get to use this code a lot so you've made a big difference here!

Comment: Glad you like it. It might be a bit faster yet if you create the set `rated` in one go, as in your self-answer; I didn't do that because I didn't know what else is going on in your actual code. But your real problem were the repeated scans of long lists, so how you build the set is minor by comparison. (Still: Run some timing tests and find out for yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some maths... If you have 40,000 entries in your DB and you need to check 500 words (with no special apparent rules), you would need to perform 20,000,000 comparisons. This is NOT a small task.

Secondly, and assuming you are comparing strings (words), you are also doing some CASE manipulations (e.g. making sure that "RED" "Red", "REd", "ReD",..., "red" are considered the same value).

So, all in all, you should expect this to take few seconds at least. but not HOURS (unless you are using an 8086 processor :-)).

Last, your code appears to be incomplete and hence cannot be examined.

Comment: Yeah, I know the scale of the problem: you'll see that I already mentioned the 20 million figure in my original post. How is the code incomplete, though? The 'rating' variable returns the value I want; what have I left out that's relevant?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got some advice from someone offline that made a big difference here; it might be useful for anyone who comes looking with a similar problem. It seems my biggest bottleneck was in the line:

```
elif i not in unrated and i not in data.values:
```

This is because data.values is an array, and it takes time to search. Creating a variable

```
words = set(data1['Word'].values)
```

that turns the array into a set and putting that into the loop instead of the array dropped execution time from 1 hour+ to about 3 mins. That's still slow, but it's better than what it was.